# Modifying a commonly used method's return type to it's subtype

Tags: java

in the current project, we use a common module. I have changed one method's return type to it's subtype. This is not breaking the build or anything but somehow I don't feel comfortable with this. Let me give an example.

```
class Child extends Parent{
    ...
}
```

in another file, let's say components

```
public static Parent getFancyComponent(){
    return new Child();
}
```

Somehow, someone made the return type as `Parent` even though the created object's type is `Child`. There is no problem until now. But another person created a method like this;

```
public static getFancyColumn(Child child,String name){
    ...
}
```

Now, if I want to use getFancyComponent method here, I have to cast the type

```
getFancyColumn((Child)getFancyComponent(), "fancy");
```

After this type cast here, I decided to change the return type of the getFancyComponent method to the `Child`. I would like to hear your ideas. And consider that there are at least hundreds of usage of this `getFancyComponent()` method. Would this action cause any invisible problem?

Comment: So you want to change it to avoid having to cast the returned value all the time?

Comment: Yeah that's the main reason. This method has written like 4 years ago but until now everything was alright till I had to cast it in 10 places.

Comment: I'd be inclined to leave it as is, being such an old system. Are there any other subtypes of 'Parent'? Is it likely that new subtypes might be added in future?

Comment: Yes @khriskooper, there are other subtypes as well. I have never had a situation like this before. It seems so innocent but it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't feel comfortable because the change that you want to make is essentially irreversible.

You can easily replace the return type `Parent` by `Child` now, because every `Child` *is also* a `Parent`.

However, you won't be able to revert this by replacing `Child` by `Parent` again, because a `Parent` is not necessarily a `Child`. And you will also not be able to change the return type to some `Child2` that extends `Parent`, if you all of the sudden find out that you wanted `Child2` instead of `Child`.

If you change it to `Child`, whatever abstraction leaks in `Child`s signature to the outside, you will not be able to change it, unless you break code that depends on it.

Are you even sure that you want to return classes with their uncanny inheritance hierarchies, instead of a small lean interface? Maybe it's not too late to replace `Parent` by a minimalistic interface instead, without breaking too much. This would be more difficult now, but it would be easier to deal with in the longer term. If you simply replace `Parent` by a `Child` subclass, then it might be comfortable right now, but then you've irreversibly increased entropy in your codebase.

It doesn't mean that you should never change anything, this is certainly not what I want to express here. But you should be aware of the consequences, and if you decide to change the return type from `Parent` to `Child`, make sure that `Child` doesn't leak anything that is not strictly necessary. That is, if `Parent` was a single-method abstract class, you definitely shouldn't replace it by a `Child` that inherits twenty methods from ten other superclasses.

Comment: I accepted this one, since it enlightens the point that it is not reversible.

Comment: Good point about considering an interface here too. Perhaps that was the original intention.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't cause any problems since a subtype implies an "IS-A" relationship. Anywhere where you use `getFancyComponent()` will be fine since a `Child` "IS-A" `Parent`.

HOWEVER, if the documentation isn't specific that `getFancyComponent()` will return a child or if you think it's possible that this method could be changed in the future to return a non-child Parent subclass I would leave it alone.

An alternative is to just create another method called something like `getChildFancyComponent()` that is used to specifically return a child object.